# Postgresql remove integer value on particular index

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have integer array {0,23,**1**,29,0,15,1} postgres(V 9.3.6) and i want to remove particular element which highlighted above using it's index for example it's 3 as of now i get those element index using function **idx**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION idx(anyarray, anyelement)
    RETURNS int AS 
$$
SELECT i FROM (
    SELECT generate_series(array_lower($1,1),array_upper($1,1))
) g(i)
WHERE $1[i] = $2
LIMIT 1;
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

But I'm unable to found any built in function in postgres which allows removal by using index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create or replace function idx(the_array anyarray, idx integer)
returns anyarray as $$

    select array_agg(a order by i)
    from (
        select
            generate_series(1, array_upper(the_array, 1)),
            unnest(the_array)
    ) s(i, a)
    where i != idx

; $$ language sql;

select idx(array[0,23,1,29,0,15,1], 3);
       idx        
------------------
 {0,23,29,0,15,1}
```